# How to decode the value encoded as one*100 + two*10 + three?

Tags: java

How to get values `one`, `two` and `three` back?
Is the following approach correct? Looks like no.

```
int EncodedValue = one*100 + two*10 + three;

// the following decryption is part of another procedure
int one = EncodedValue / 100;
int two = EncodedValue / 10;
int three = EncodedValue % 10;
```

Comment: one, two and three are always in 0..9

Comment: You should edit your comment into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `two` and `three` are originally in the range 0-9 (otherwise you have ambiguity) you want:

```
int two = (encodedValue / 10) % 10;
```

... otherwise it basically gets ten times the `one` value added to it.

Comment: Your assumption is indeed in the OP's comment.

Comment: @mellamokb: Oops - I saw there was a comment, I didn't realise it was from the OP (glanced too quickly).

Answer (score 1):

That won't quite work. While I can't speak to the efficiency of the following, it does work:

```
int encoded = one*100+two*10+three
int one = encoded/100;
int two = (encoded-100*one)/10;
int three = encoded - 100*one - 10*two;
```

Mind you, this only works if all those variables are a single digit.
It could also be implemented recursively to allow for numbers of any length to be decomposed to their digits, but the it may be less intensive to simply convert to a string and then a character array.